# Problems accessing page with python requests

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm trying to extract the sector of a stock for a ML classification project. If I go to the following page:

https://www.six-swiss-exchange.com/shares/security_info_en.html?id=CH0012221716CHF4

I get (on the screen) some information about this stock (it changes, with the id code - I just pick the first one of the list). However, none of the information is available on a regular request. (The html page contains mostly javascript functions)

What I need is on the "Shares Details" tab (ICB Supersector at the bottom of the page). Once again nothing is available with a regular requests. I looked into what happens when I click this tab and the desired request is inside the url:

http://www.six-swiss-exchange.com/shares/info_details_en.html?id=CH0210483332CHF4&portalSegment=EQ&dojo.preventCache=1520360103852 HTTP/1.1

However, if I use this url directly, I get an 403 error from requests but work from a browser. I usually don't have any problems with this sort of things but in this case, do I have to submit cookies or any other information to access that page - no login is required and it can be easily accessed from any browser.

I am thinking 1) make a first request to the url that works, 2) store the cookie they send you (I don't know how to do that really) and 3) make a second request to the desired url. Would this work?

I tried using request.session() but I'm not sure if this is the solution or if I implemented it properly.

If anyone has dealt with that sort of problem, I would love any pointers in solving this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from urllib.parse import urljoin

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

BASE_URL = 'https://www.six-swiss-exchange.com'


def get_page_html(isin):
    params = {
        'id': isin,
        'portalSegment': 'EQ'
    }
    r = requests.get(
        '{}/shares/info_details_en.html'.format(BASE_URL),
        params=params
    )
    r.raise_for_status()
    return r.text


def get_supersector_info(soup):
    supersector = soup.find('td', text='ICB Supersector').next_sibling.a
    return {
        'link': urljoin(BASE_URL, supersector['href']),
        'text': supersector.text
    }


if __name__ == '__main__':
    page_html = get_page_html('CH0012221716CHF4')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page_html, 'lxml')
    supersector_info = get_supersector_info(soup)
```

Console:

```
https://www.six-swiss-exchange.com/search/quotes_en.html?security=C2700T
Industrial Goods & Services
```

Comment: This is great, thank you very much! What if I would want to have all the html of that page - inside a 'soup' let's say. If not possible, that's ok as I can extract any other information (industry and subsector) in the same way.

Comment: I am not as versed as you are with this sort of thing but I am comfortable enough with your answer to move along (I realized that what was missing in my request was the param portalSegment :EQ). That being said, I would be interested in knowing a bit more about the API calls as they are indeed easier to deal with. Thanks again in advance - answer accepted.

Comment: I've seen them as well in the network tab(last two). They contains the data to generate the charts. The sectors for which I was interested were in an html file. But with the proper params I can get them now. Thanks to you!